# Tax situation of Indian lady becoming foreigner after marriage

Tags: income-tax, india

What will happen to an Indian citizen's income tax file when she gets married to a foreigner and acquires foreign citizenship?

Can she apply for an Aadhaar card as a foreign resident in India? In order to operate her bank account she needs Aadhaar card.

Comment: After acquiring foreign citizenship where is the person residing? Is there any previous income generated or future income generated by the person in India?

Answer (score 1):

**What will happen to an Indian citizen's income tax file when she gets married to a foreigner and acquires foreign citizenship?**

> [An income](https://cleartax.in/guide/income-tax-filing-for-foreign-nationals) which is earned by an expatriate in India is taxable in
>   India irrespective of the foreign national's citizenship or
>   residential status.This payment may also be subjected to TDS (Tax
>   Deducted at Source) in India.
>
> If your total income is less than the minimum exempt income (Rs
>   2,50,000 for FY 2014-15) you can get a refund of this TDS by filing an
>   Income Tax Return in India.
>
> An expatriate in India is someone who comes to live in India and is
>   not a citizen of India.

So she will still need to file taxes, she may be taxed differently. It would be best to consult an accountant proficient in Indian tax codes.

**Can she apply for an Aadhaar card as a foreign resident in India?**

> [AADHAAR card](https://aadharcarduid.com/aadhaar-card-nri-foreigner) is available free of cost to all citizen and
>   residents of India, including NRIs and resident foreign nationals,
>   regardless of the their citizenship.